# Vuetify v-checkbox - selections not updating correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I dynamically generate a grid of checkboxes from a list of judges, each of which get a checkbox for a list of tests.

Updating the selections works fine when I modify a single judge's selections, but there's a problem when I change more than one judge's selections.

Also, checking almost any box messes up all the other judges' selections.

HTML :

```
<v-container fluid>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="3">
          tests per judges
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3" v-for="test in tests">
          {{ test.name }}
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row v-for="judge in judges">
        <v-col cols="3">
          {{ judge.name }} - {{ judge.tests.map(t => t.id)}}
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3" v-for="test in tests">
          <v-checkbox v-model="judge.tests" :value="{id: test.id, reference: test.reference}"/>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <p v-for="judge in judges">
        {{ judge }}
      </p>
</v-container>
```

JS :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      tests: [
        {id: 0, name: "test 0", reference: 'T25F'},
        {id: 1, name: "test 1", reference: 'T26F'},
        {id: 2, name: "test 2", reference: 'T27F'}
      ],
      judges: [
        { id: 0, name: 'judge name 1', tests: [{id: 0, reference:'T25F' }, {id: 1, reference: 'T26F'}] },
        { id: 1, name: 'judge name 2', tests: [{id: 0, reference:'T25F' }] },
        { id: 2, name: 'judge name 3', tests: [{id: 0, reference:'T25F' }, {id: 2, reference:'T27F' }] }
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/Agathe02515/pen/GRgJygz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think some wires got crossed passing the entire `test` object as the value.

Here's what I found works:

```
...
      <v-row v-for="judge in judges">
        <v-col cols="3">
          {{ judge.name }} - {{ judge.tests }}
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="3" v-for="test, idx in tests">
          <v-checkbox v-model="judge.tests" :value="test.id">
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
...
</div>
```

The data for `judges` starting out is this:

```
      judges: [
        { id: 0, name: 'judge name 1', tests: [0, 1] },
        { id: 1, name: 'judge name 2', tests: [0]},
        { id: 2, name: 'judge name 3', tests: [0, 2] }
      ]
```

Saving only the list of selected `test.id`s to each judge simplifies things, and lets you reason more clearly about the logic of `v-model`.

Fork of your codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ebbishop/pen/NWPqMYN?editors=1111).